# Disable button until fields are entered in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, validation

How to disable a save button until all the fields are filled in so it prevents the user from continuing until they enter something.

How can I do that in Swift?

Comment: here you go, http://sourcefreeze.com/uitextfield-and-uitextfield-delegate-in-swift/

Answer (score 2):

First write a method to check for your textfield's text and only enable the button if the text fields contain valid text:

```
func checkField(sender: AnyObject) {
    if textField1.text.isEmpty || textField2.text.isEmpty 
    {
       yourbutton.enabled = false

    }
   else
    {
     yourbutton.enabled = true
    }
}
```

Then call your function from the text field's delegate method `textFieldDidEndEditing`so that when the user finishes editing a field the button is enabled/disabled correctly.